# DevOps pipeline CI error when I updated .net core 3.1 to .net core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

So I updated all the projects of my solution to .net core 6, before every single one was .net core 3.1.

Then I started to get the following error in build step:

```
##[error]PjInspe.Tests\PjInspe.Tests.csproj(0,0): Error NU1201: 
Project PjInspe.Aplicacao is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 
(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project PjInspe.Aplicacao supports: 
net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
```

But all the projects has this in the .csproj

[image]

And its the only project that is failing

Any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT:

My pipeline YAML

Iam using the windows 2022 to run the CI and I've seen the sdk from the net6 on the build logs

```yaml
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*Project.csproj'
    vstsFeed: '***************'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '$(Parameters.TestProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Comment: You likely just need to add the _Use .NET Core SDK_ task (`UseDotNet@2`) to your pipeline, and set it to use the .NET Core 6 SDK. I don't _believe_ that Azure DevOps has been updated to use the .NET Core 6 SDK by default yet.

Comment: @JeremyCaney everything compiles just fine, I set it to use the windows 2022 that already have the .net 6 sdk just that project and I dont get it why

Comment: For us to investigate this question further, could you please share your [pipeline definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwYwx.png)?And don't forget to remove your in-private information

Comment: @JasonPan I Added the pipeline YAML, and iam using the windows 2022 to build to .net 6

Comment: Why dont you try adding this task to your pipeline 
 - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET 6 Core sdk'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '6.0.x'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is supposted to be to modify you dotnetcore cli task as follows

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    version: '6.0.x' //better to put this in a variable
    projects: '$(Parameters.TestProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

But I still had a similar build problem. I fixed it by using the **use dotnet core task BEFORE all other tasks** and specifying the version I need.
[image]

This is the yaml code that I used

```
 - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET 6 Core sdk'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '6.0.x'
```

Comment: Iam going to try it later, thanks for the answer, hopping that can fix it